# Can you control proxy settings for the connection to the SmartTarget webservice?

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget

I am getting proxy related errors in the SmartTarget (2014 SP1) GUI. If I connect to the SmartTarget web service in a browser on the CMS server, I get the same error. If I turn off the proxy in the browser it connects OK. I don't see any mention of being able to control proxy settings in the SmartTarget docs.

Is it possible to stop SmartTarget using a proxy (or indeed to configure the proxy it uses, rather than have it pick it up automatically from the server settings)?

Comment: I have the same problem, only with the Session Preview service. I can configure a Content Delivery Endpoint URL, but no proxy settings. As a result, the CM uses the default proxy settings on my machine rather than connect to the OData service directly.

Comment: On Windows Tridion indeed picks up the proxy settings for the user it is running in. For system users running on a server that is fine but on you local developer machine that can raise this issue. For local development: why not disable the system proxy and set the proxy in the brower (works for Chrome and FF).

Answer (score 1):

You can control the proxy that gets used by a web application from the applicable web.config file; see [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx) on how that is done.

You can of course also configure the system proxy through IE; it should normally be correctly configured anyway or other process on the server might also not work...